# Send mail with attachment by Mailgun API using Python's httpx library

Tags: python, mailgun, httpx

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment using Mailgun API. I can easily achieve this using curl:

```
curl -V -s --user 'XXX' \
    https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/XXX/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to='XXXX' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
    --form-string html='<html>HTML version of the body</html>' \
    -F attachment=@files/example.csv
```

the same using python's requests library. But when I'm trying to do the same using httpx library:

```
build_request_kwargs: dict = {
    "url": "/messages",
    "method": "POST",
    "data": {
        "template": "template_name",
        "from": from_,
        "to": to,
        "subject": subject,
        "h:X-Mailgun-Variables": json.dumps(template_data),
    },
    "files": [("file", ("file", io.BytesIO(b"<file content>")))]
}

client = httpx.AsyncClient(base_url=base_url, auth=("api", api_key))
async with client:
    request = client.build_request(**build_request_kwargs)
    response = await client.send(request)
    response.raise_for_status()
```

email is delivered but without any attachment. I was trying to set each file encoding to `application/octet-stream` but it didn't work either. I'm not sure what's the difference between curl or requests `multipart/form-data` request and httpx.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I need to post each file as "attachment" form name. This example should work:

```
build_request_kwargs: dict = {
    "url": "/messages",
    "method": "POST",
    "data": {
        "template": "template_name",
        "from": from_,
        "to": to,
        "subject": subject,
        "h:X-Mailgun-Variables": json.dumps(template_data),
    },
    "files": [("attachment", ("file.txt", io.BytesIO(b"<file content>")))]
}

client = httpx.AsyncClient(base_url=base_url, auth=("api", api_key))
async with client:
    request = client.build_request(**build_request_kwargs)
    response = await client.send(request)
    response.raise_for_status()
```